# Is there anyway to show View without pushing it to Nav Controller

Tags: iphone

I've a question, I want to show a View with out Pushing it to nav controller, it is very similar as with Native email UI, you go to Inbox folder and there you select "Compose" screen, compose screen is just animate from bottom to up without pushing this screen to nav controller.

How can i do the same thing?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3):

You can show any view controller as a "modal" view on top of the current nav/tab view controller, e.g.:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

This gives you the "slide in" animation for free.  You do need to arrange for the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to be called on the nav controller when you're done with the modal view, though.  See [the reference for UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController:animated:)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just add it as a subview of your window rather than pushing it to the nav controller.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel was hinting to, presenting modal views is a UIViewController behavior, UInavigationController just inherits this from its superclass.

There is no need to have a UINavigationController to get this effect.